# Rust secp256k1 equivalent of NodeJS `crypto::ECDH::computeSecret()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, secp256k1

I've written this working NodeJS/Javascript function:

```
/*
 * Calculate the Symmetric Key from the Public and Secret keys from two
 * different key pairs.
 * 
 * Note: symmetric_key(publicA, secretB) == symmetric_key(publicB, secretA)
 */
function symmetric_key(pkey, skey) {
        const ephemeral = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
        ephemeral.setPublicKey(pkey);
        const centre = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
        centre.setPrivateKey(skey);
        return centre.computeSecret(ephemeral.getPublicKey());
}
```

I'm trying to understand how I can use the Rust `secp256k1` library to do the same.

Looking at [secp256k1::SecretKey's methods](https://docs.rs/secp256k1/latest/secp256k1/struct.SecretKey.html#implementations) I cannot see a direct equivalent.

- What is that library's version of `computeSecret()` called?
- If it doesn't have an analogous method, how can I compute the required secret?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: [ECDH SharedSecret](https://docs.rs/secp256k1/latest/secp256k1/ecdh/struct.SharedSecret.html)

Struct secp256k1::ecdh::SharedSecret

```
pub struct SharedSecret(_);
```

Enables two parties to create a shared secret without revealing their own secrets.

Examples

```
let s = Secp256k1::new();
let (sk1, pk1) = s.generate_keypair(&mut rand::thread_rng());
let (sk2, pk2) = s.generate_keypair(&mut rand::thread_rng());
let sec1 = SharedSecret::new(&pk2, &sk1);
let sec2 = SharedSecret::new(&pk1, &sk2);
assert_eq!(sec1, sec2);
```

Comment: Note: While this serves the same function, the shared secrets calculated in Rust do match those from NodeJS.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755083/rust-ecdh-does-not-produce-the-same-shared-secret-as-nodejs-javascript-and-c-imp